# Android - How to parse specific values from JSON Array and display Toast

Tags: java, android, json

New to Android and Java in general and I'm learning how to make a JSON call. To do so, I'm following this guide: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/consuming-json-services-android-apps

Here's where things get confusing for me. The author of that tutorial wants the reader to call this API: http://ws.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=37lng=122

Which returns a JSON object in this format:

```
            {
                "weatherObservation": {
                     "clouds":"scattered clouds",
                     "weatherCondition":"n/a",
                     "observation":"KCFV 090852Z AUTO 06005KT 
                      10SM SCT090 SCT110 24/20 A3000 RMK AO2 
                      SLP148 T02390200 53002",
                     "windDirection":60,
                     "ICAO":"KCFV",
                     "seaLevelPressure":1014.8,
                     "elevation":225,
                     "countryCode":"US",
                     "lng":-95.56666666666666,
                     "temperature":"23.9",
                     "dewPoint":"20",
                     "windSpeed":"05",
                     "humidity":78,
                     "stationName":"Coffeyville, Coffeyville 
                                 Municipal Airport",
                     "datetime":"2012-07-09 08:52:00",
                     "lat":37.083333333333336
                }
            }
```

Pretty straight forward, except that the API is no longer valid/has limits. In order to finish the project I've instead opted to call this API: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=37.77&lon=-122.419

Which returns the JSON in this format

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 139,
        "lat": 35
    },
    "sys": {
        "country": "JP",
        "sunrise": 1369769524,
        "sunset": 1369821049
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04n"
        }
    ],
    "main": {
        "temp": 289.5,
        "humidity": 89,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "temp_min": 287.04,
        "temp_max": 292.04
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.31,
        "deg": 187.002
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "dt": 1369824698,
    "id": 1851632,
    "name": "Shuzenji",
    "cod": 200
}
```

I can make the call just fine, but how do I display the "main" and "description" strings in the "weather" array? More specifically, how do I display this information as a Toast?

Here's what I have:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        try {


            JSONArray weatherArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONArray wArray = new JSONArray("weather");

            String mainWeather = wArray.getString(1);
            String mainDescription = wArray.getString(2);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mainWeather + " - "
                        + mainDescription,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

BecauseI am following the mobiforge Tutorial, I have not deviated anywhere else except for this particular block of code.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**
There are several solutions here that work see @swats and @user3515851. I have chosen @remees-m-syde due to it's simplicity. Primarily because his solution did not require that I go through the for loop.

Comment: You should have a look at Gson. It'll change your life when it comes to json parsing in java. You create a simple object that matches the json result and use gson to parse it. Very straight forward

Comment: Thanks Neil. Will look into it once I get the basics down.

Comment: Would you like an answer on the Gson topic?

Comment: No thank you, not at the moment. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why the solutions here work/don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unable to get the data because there is one json object inside the "weather" JSONArray.

JSONArray starts with - [

JSONObject starts with - {,

So first get the JSONArray and then the JSONObject inside it.

```
"weather": [                          ----Array
        {                             ----Object
            "id": 804,
            "main": "clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04n"
        }
    ]
```

You have to get this JSONObject and then get the String from it like the below code showing.

```
    JSONObject weatherArray = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray wArray = weatherArray.getJSONArray("weather");
    JSONObject jobj = wArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String mainWeather = jobj.getString("main");
    String mainDescription = jobj.getString("description");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mainWeather + " - "
                                + mainDescription,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When there is multiple object in Array, Get it as below.

```
JSONObject rootJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
     JSONArray wArray = rootJsonObj.optJSONArray("weather");
     for (int i = 0; i < wArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject weatherJsonObj = wArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String mainWeather = weatherJsonObj.getString("main");
          String mainDescription = weatherJsonObj.getString("description");

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mainWeather + " - "
                      + mainDescription,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Comment: Hi Remees - your solution provides this error: 
'D/ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask﹕ Value weather of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray'

Could you elaborate on your object within the weather comment? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Works! I actually prefer your solution because I don't have to step through the for loop. Two questions though: why does your solution NOT have to step through the loop? why do you put 0 inside wArray.getJSONObject?

Comment: Because in your response your getting only one object like {   }, so i am getting the 1st object which is in the 0th position. if there are "n" number of objects you have to use loop.

Comment: So for any similar JSON, where there is a fixed number of objects, I can do the same? Set the 0th position and then just call whatever object I'm searching for?

Comment: For fixed json you can do it, but Dynamic you have to use the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71852/discussion-between-remees-m-syde-and-tlxwiggum).

Answer (score 5):

I have used `optJSONArray` or  `optString`, instead of `getJSONArray` or  `getString` as "opt" will return "" if there is no value for that key.. it will not throw any `exception` like in case of `getString()`

Try below code

```
     JSONObject rootJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
     JSONArray wArray = rootJsonObj.optJSONArray("weather");
     for (int i = 0; i < wArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject weatherJsonObj = wArray.optJSONObject(i);
          String mainWeather = weatherJsonObj.optString("main");
          String mainDescription = weatherJsonObj.optString("description");

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mainWeather + " - "
                      + mainDescription,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Parsing issue was there, You should have taken object from response result.

**EDIT:** No need of try catch block while using `optJSONArray` or `optString`.

Comment: why not spend some time investigating alternatives and use faster xml Jackson for Json parsing?

Comment: @user3515851 I followed convention in the above code. If you have used the same so its code. It does not mean that I have copied your code

Comment: #Swati Aggarwal: Yeah you r copy from my code.that s what i am telling.such an irritating fellows

Comment: I have used optString() method, you have not.. so double check before commenting.

Comment: @SwatiAggarwal no need of try catch block here.

Comment: Hi Swati - thanks for your input, what do you mean by "Parsing issue was there, You should have taken object from response result."?   Also, thanks for the tip re: 'optJSONArray' and 'optString' - can those be used interchangeably with 'getJSONArray' and 'getString'?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    try {


        JSONObject weatherArray = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray wArray = weatherArray.getJSONArray("weather");
        for(int i=0;i<wArray.length,i++){
        JSONObject object=wArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String mainWeather=object.getString("main");
        String mainDescription=object.getString("description");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mainWeather + " - "
                    + mainDescription,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

I hope this one will help to you :)

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Could you explain why it did? I'm assuming it's necessary to step through the array to get the values?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you obtained the weather array from parsing this JSON now to retrieve the values from it

```
JSONObject  object=null;
try {
            JSONObject  object=array.getJSONObject(0);
            String main=object.getString("main");  
            String description=object.getString("description");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and now use the strings in your toast

Comment: Hi Pramod - in order to use your solution I would have to parse the JSON before hand? Why would I want/need to do that if I always want a specific set of values?   Thank you!

Comment: because you can't get the weather array without parsing the JSON as it the part of the JSON output you are getting,so to get that JSON array you have to parse it from the output you are getting,i would rather prefer you should use jackson or gson libraries to handle json

Answer (score 0):

Assuming result contains the JSON, here is how to get main, and description form weather :

```
  JSONObject resJSON = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONArray weatherArray = resJSON.getJSONArray("weather");

  for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject weatherJSON = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println(weatherJSON.getString("main"));
      System.out.println(weatherJSON.getString("description"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    JSONObject weatherObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray wArray = weatherObject.getJSONArray("weather");
    for (int i = 0; i < wArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject wObject = wArray.getJSONObject(i);
      if(wObject.has("description")) {
        Log.d("TAG", wObject.getString("description"));
      }
      if(wObject.has("main")) {
        Log.d("TAG", wObject.getString("main"));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I found out [json2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) useful tool for json parsing, works with anything Jackson,Gson,Java etc. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: link-only answers are poor practice,. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
                JSONObject weatherArray = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray wArray = new JSONArray("weather");

                String mainWeather = ((JSONObject)wArray.getJSONObject(0)).getString("main");
                String mainDescription = ((JSONObject)wArray.getJSONObject(0)).getString("description");

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mainWeather + " - "
                            + mainDescription,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: why use JSONObject etc when fantastic libraries like faster xml Jackson exist?

Comment: @Hector there is no point of giving negative rating here. the answer is absolutely correct and why to add any third part library, if android already provide the support

Comment: whats negative about my comment? which word or phrase is negative? android provided solution is in adequate with regard performance and simplicity. Lets not settle for the first solution we think of.