# How to access member of onActivityResult() outside of it in any other function in Android

Tags: android, json, base64, android-camera

This is my oncreate method with logic of capturing image from camera:-

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driverregister);
    app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
    btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
    driverPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);
    driverName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.driverName);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    contactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
    licenseNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.licenseNumber);


    btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // create intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // to save picture remove comment
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    "my-photo.jpg");
    Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(file);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);
    intent.putExtra("data", true);
    setResult(1, intent);
    // start camera activity
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);


    System.out.println("driverName: "+driverName.getText());
    System.out.println("Address: "+address.getText());
    System.out.println("String is"+encodedImage);
    System.out.println("photo path is"+photoPath);

}
```

This is the onActivityResult() function where I am writing logic for converting the image to base64 and then to string. I want to post in application/json format along with my other form fields in my form submit part.
When try to print the `encodedImage` it shows null every time but this will be printed in the `onActivityResult()` which is below:-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){
        // get bundle
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        // get
        bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        driverPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
         /* Code for Image */
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)driverPhoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("byte array:"+image);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
       // img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
       // System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
       // app.setImgString(img_str);
        System.out.println("string:"+encodedImage);
    }
}
```

I want to access this encodedImage outside of it and use it as global variable so that I can post in JSON format instead of multipart.

Comment: my advice would be to not take image from data as it only gives thumbnail of the image nt the real image

Comment: @sur007: is it ! then what i should take?

Comment: yeah it is. Better u save image in memory and retrieve back whenever you need it and later delete it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Broadcast Notifications](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-broadcast-receiver-notification-tutorial/)?

On `onActivityResult` method broadcast the result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("ACTIVITY_RESULT");
intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
intent.putExtra("resultCode", resultCode);
intent.putExtra("encodedImage", encodedImage);
getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In any Activity you can register for your Broadcast message like this:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // stufs...
     IntentFilter intentFilter = new  IntentFilter("ACTIVITY_RESULT");
     this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
     // other stufs...
}


//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for Notification broadcasts
public final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    // get notification action
    if (action.equals("ACTIVITY_RESULT")) {
        // get encoded image extra parameter 
        String encodedImage = intent.getStringExtra("encodedImage");
        // get others parameters...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and for more info, you could check any tutorial about [Broadcast Receivers](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers) that you found.

Comment: Adrian C.: i dont want notification i want the variable inside onActivityResult to be used globally in Activity so  will it be done by BroadCast notification as i heard it will be used in GCM !

Comment: suri: Then first thing that comes in mind is to create a public static variable and update that one each time you have a new ActivityResult, something like MainActivity.encodedImage.

Comment: Adrian C. : where exactly i should add that part in my code?

Comment: suri: In your main activity, before OnCreate, you could declare a variable public static string crtEncodedImage = ""; In Activity Result you will set the new value like this: MainActivityName.crtEncodedImage = encodedImage; Now you will have the result visible in all the activities by refering to the variable crtEncodedImage.

Comment: @Adran C : i tried it , but its display nothing in my SOP , its blank !